# Graphing in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, graph

I would like to ask for something about the graphs in Microsoft Excel.
Is there possible I can add in the data for my loss ratio into my graph? I've made doodles in the uploaded graph, I want to add in something like that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that one of those columns, blue or grey, is the LR, and you just want to display that number?

Comment: The bar chart is apparently my Gross earned premium, I wish to add in my loss ratio also to each of my products for comparison.

Comment: You could add it in and put it on a secondary axis.

Comment: How could I add it just like my doodle ?

Comment: You could manually add in with a Shape...?

Answer (score 1):

As BruceWayne said, LostRatio must be placed on the secondary axis, then turn on DataLabel for the respective columns, then format Fill = No fill and Border = No line, then just move DataLabel to the correct positions.
[image]